# How to make collision work with translate UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, 2d-games, rigid-bodies

I can't use rigidbody method to move player so i need to move it with **Transform.translate**

I know collision work only with rigidbody but i don't want make it like that

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use ribidbody method to move player"? Are you allowed to have a rigidobdy component at least?

Comment: You can have a rigidbody on the player and still move him using `Transform.translate`. Having a rigidbody on either of the colliders is necessary for the collision to be detected between them, and of course, both of them must have a collider.

Comment: Moving the player directly will skip physics behaviour for that object on the next physics update. It's possible to do but without re-writing a bunch of physics code yourself it's going to be very janky

Answer (score 0):

you could cast a ray to detect collisions. this is just a simple script where collision is detected in the forward direction of the transform one frame before it happens (with a simple cube of size 1 unit).

```
public float speed;
bool collision;

void Update()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, 0.5f + speed * Time.deltaTime))
    {
        collision = true;
    }
    else collision = false;
    if (!collision)
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```